# Split data frame by a repetitive column

Tags: r

I have data frame like this:

```
p1=rnorm(7)
p2=rnorm(7)
p3=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3)

df=data.frame(p1,p2,p3)


df

         p1         p2 p3
1 -0.7843568  0.6383588  1
2 -0.4073465  0.3480860  1
3  0.2799414 -0.1938586  2
4 -1.3496633 -0.5271080  2
5 -1.5750376  0.6178624  3
6 -0.1030045  0.8642336  3
7  0.5839070 -0.9723264  3
```

How can I split the data frame so that I can have a data frame like this:

```
        1         1           2          2             3        3
1 -0.7843568  0.6383588   0.2799414 -0.1938586  -1.5750376   0.6178624 
2 -1.3496633 -0.5271080  -0.4073465  0.3480860   -0.1030045  0.8642336
3                                                0.5839070  -0.9723264
```

Comment: @akrun 

Just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either try using `reshape` from `base R` or using other packages.  In the first step, we are creating an `indx` column for grouping purpose.  You can use `ave` to create a `sequence` for each group of `p3`, i.e. for the first two elements (`p3=1`), the corresponding `indx` will be `1,2` and it does the same for the remaining groups as well.  After the `indx` creation step, you can directly use `reshape` and specify the `direction` to `wide`.

```
df1 <- transform(df, indx=ave(p3,p3, FUN=seq_along))
reshape(df1, idvar='indx', timevar='p3', direction='wide')
#     indx       p1.1      p2.1       p1.2       p2.2       p1.3       p2.3
#1    1 -0.7843568 0.6383588  0.2799414 -0.1938586 -1.5750376  0.6178624
#2    2 -0.4073465 0.3480860 -1.3496633 -0.5271080 -0.1030045  0.8642336
#7    3         NA        NA         NA         NA  0.5839070 -0.9723264
```

Or you can use `getanID` from `splitstackshape` to generate the `indx` column and use it in combination with `reshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
reshape(getanID(df, 'p3'), direction='wide', idvar='.id', timevar='p3')
 #   .id       p1.1      p2.1       p1.2       p2.2       p1.3       p2.3
 #1:   1 -0.7843568 0.6383588  0.2799414 -0.1938586 -1.5750376  0.6178624
 #2:   2 -0.4073465 0.3480860 -1.3496633 -0.5271080 -0.1030045  0.8642336
 #3:   3         NA        NA         NA         NA  0.5839070 -0.9723264
```

Or using `dcast/melt`.  You can specify the `fill` argument.  The default will be `NA`.  Here, I used `''`, but it will convert the column classes to character.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(df1, id.var=c('p3','indx')), 
       indx~p3+variable, value.var='value', fill='')
#  indx       1_p1      1_p2       2_p1       2_p2       3_p1       3_p2
#1    1 -0.7843568 0.6383588  0.2799414 -0.1938586 -1.5750376  0.6178624
#2    2 -0.4073465  0.348086 -1.3496633  -0.527108 -0.1030045  0.8642336
#3    3                                              0.583907 -0.9723264
```

Or using `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df1, Var, Val, p1:p2) %>% 
                            unite(p3Var, p3, Var) %>%
                            spread(p3Var,Val, fill=0)

#  indx       1_p1      1_p2       2_p1       2_p2       3_p1       3_p2
#1    1 -0.7843568 0.6383588  0.2799414 -0.1938586 -1.5750376  0.6178624
#2    2 -0.4073465 0.3480860 -1.3496633 -0.5271080 -0.1030045  0.8642336
#3    3  0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.5839070 -0.9723264
```

Comment: Can you explain the first attempt in more detail?

Comment: @Trik23 I added some text to it. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks, You showed me the `getanID` in an earlier post.

Comment: @akrun

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @akrun

Is there a way to remove NAs? If I use `na.omit` I get a strange data frame.

Comment: @Trik23 As I showed in the post, you can use `fill=0` in the `dcast` or in the `spread`.  Otherwise, if `res` is the result, `res[is.na(res)] <- 0` If you want to remove the rows, `res[complete.cases(res),]`

Comment: @akrun
Thaks a lot again!